# Parent registering child's method: how to avoid the design anti-patterns?

Tags: c++, anti-patterns

```
struct Base {
  void foo(??? fn) {
    // do something with fn
  }
};

struct A : Base {
  A() : Base() { ... }
  void aa() { ... }
  void aaa() { ... }
};

struct B : Base {
  B() : Base() { ... }
  void bb() { ... }
};

int main() {
  A a, B b;
  a.foo(a.aa); // foo works with aa()
  a.foo(a.aaa); // foo works with aaa()
  b.foo(b.bb); // foo works with bb()
  return 0;
}
```

I'd like `fn` to be some member function (returns void, no parameters) of child class of `Base`. It seems like a bad design: parents should not be aware of their childs. However, to write the functionality into every child class leads to code duplicity. I'd like to have the childs as thin as possible.

What would be the best design to achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: I guess I also consider using structs in situations like these to be an anti-pattern.  Although there can be some edge cases, normally I think that once you start adding constructors, methods, and polymorphism, you should probably make these classes.  Just my personal preference, though.

Comment: Struct and class are functionally identical.

Comment: @user315052: thank you, too - but your reason is disputable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use method pointers.

```
struct Base {
  template <typename D>
  void foo(void(D::*fn)()) {
    D *d = static_cast<D *>(this);
    (d->*(fn))();
  }
};

  A a; B b;
  a.foo(&A::aa); // foo works with aa()
  a.foo(&A::aaa); // foo works with aaa()
  b.foo(&B::bb); // foo works with bb()
```

If you want better type safety, you should use `dynamic_cast`, but you need to add a virtual destructor so that the dynamic type inference can be made:

```
struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() {}
  template <typename D>
  void foo(void(D::*fn)()) {
    D *d = dynamic_cast<D *>(this);
    if (d == 0) throw 0;
    (d->*(fn))();
  }
};

  b.foo(&B::bb); // ok
  b.foo(&A::aa); // exception thrown
```

Answer (score 3):

Say hello to `std::function<void()>`, which performs exactly the task of abstracting any function which returns void and has no parameters.

Edit: Why not simply use a virtual function? Like

```
struct Base {
private:
  virtual void fn() = 0;
public:
  void foo() {
    // do something with fn
  }
};

struct A : Base {
  A() : Base() { ... }
  void fn() { ... }
};

struct B : Base {
  B() : Base() { ... }
  void fn() { ... }
};

int main() {
  A a, B b;
  a.foo(); // foo works with aaa()
  b.foo(); // foo works with bb()
  return 0;
}
```

Does limit you to only one overriding function per derived class, though.

Comment: Because the override logic is the same in every class which leads to code duplicity.

Comment: No, I meant, making say `aaa` a virtual function, not `foo` itself.

Comment: If the override logic is the same in every class then why do you need to override it all?

Comment: You don't need the PMF if it's virtual.

Comment: It should be noted here that the parameterless base class constructor is implicitly called when the derived class is constructed.

Comment: This is an example of the Non-Virtual Interface idiom. You can read more about it here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface

Comment: No. I need multiple "overriding" functions, to decide it at runtime and `Base::fn` should not be pure virtual (see my code). Can you delete the code sample from your answer?